# How to get a JavaScript value when passing a appropriate key in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var optList = { 
'List1': [{value: 'a', label: 'apple'}, {value: 'b', label: 'ball'}, {value: 'c', label: 'car'}, {value: 'd', label: 'doll'}, {value: 'e', label: 'egg'}],
'List2': [{value: 'f', label: 'fox'}, {value: 'g', label: 'goal'}, {value: 'h', label: 'hat'}, {value: 'i', label: 'ink'}, {value: 'j', label: 'jack'}]
};

function getValue(selectedValue){
var list1 = optList.List1;
var allKeys = Object.keys(selectedValue);

}
```

I'm trying write a javascript/angular function to get a key value from JSON list. Example: If i pass list1- 'a', then i'm expecting a return value is 'apple'.
It may be simple, i'm getting lots of errors and not getting as expected.
Could you guys please help me, thanks.

Comment: It might be better if you supply the code you have tried and how it is going wrong.

Comment: from where you got Object.keys?

Comment: See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) for object methods; [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for array methods. Also consider using a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you take a string with key and the value of `value` property and you want to get the value of `label`, you could iterate the array until you find the wanted value and return the label.

```js
function getLabel(object, key) {
    var keys = key.split('-'),
        label;

    object[keys[0]].some(function (a) {
        if (a.value === keys[1]) {
            label = a.label;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return label;
}

var optList = { List1: [{ value: 'a', label: 'apple' }, { value: 'b', label: 'ball' }, { value: 'c', label: 'car' }, { value: 'd', label: 'doll' }, { value: 'e', label: 'egg' }], List2: [{ value: 'f', label: 'fox' }, { value: 'g', label: 'goal' }, { value: 'h', label: 'hat' }, { value: 'i', label: 'ink' }, { value: 'j', label: 'jack' }] };

console.log(getLabel(optList, 'List1-a'));
```

ES6

```js
function getLabel(object, key) {
    var keys = key.split('-');
    return (object[keys[0]].find(a => a.value === keys[1]) || {}).label;
}

var optList = { List1: [{ value: 'a', label: 'apple' }, { value: 'b', label: 'ball' }, { value: 'c', label: 'car' }, { value: 'd', label: 'doll' }, { value: 'e', label: 'egg' }], List2: [{ value: 'f', label: 'fox' }, { value: 'g', label: 'goal' }, { value: 'h', label: 'hat' }, { value: 'i', label: 'ink' }, { value: 'j', label: 'jack' }] };

console.log(getLabel(optList, 'List1-a'));
```

Comment: Use  `find`, not `some`.

Comment: @Bergi, it does not look like es6.

Comment: Is that relevant? The question is tagged "javascript", which doesn't limit it to ES5 :-) `find` is supported in all major environments and could be trivially shimmed otherwise, so there's no good reason not to use it when it clearly is appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: var optList = { 
'List1': [{value: 'a', label: 'apple'}, {value: 'b', label: 'ball'}, {value: 'c', label: 'car'}, {value: 'd', label: 'doll'}, {value: 'e', label: 'egg'}],
'List2': [{value: 'f', label: 'fox'}, {value: 'g', label: 'goal'}, {value: 'h', label: 'hat'}, {value: 'i', label: 'ink'}, {value: 'j', label: 'jack'}]
};                                                                                                                                           My code will pass the value, then i need to retrieve the appropriate 'label'

Comment: Example: If i pass 'a', then i'm expecting the return value is 'APPLE'

Comment: @zeraroze, i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It's working fine... Thank you guys.. I really appreciate everyones help & support